# Evaluate for matrix A

Tags: matrices, inverse

If
 $(2I-A)^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\-1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$

Evaluate for matrix A.

what i did is i got the adj( $(2I-A)^{-1}$ ) but I'm not sure if this was how the approach was supposed to be..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $(2I - A)^{-1} = B$, then $A = 2I - B^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done linear algebra for a year and a half, but I would like to give this a go.

I worked out the inverse of $2I-A$ as follows. Gauss reduce the right hand side of

$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
1&0&0 &1&1&1\\
0&1&0 &1&0&1\\
0&0&1 &-1&1&0
\end{array}\right)$$

to get

$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
1&-1&-1 &1&0&0\\
1&-1&0 &0&1&0\\
-1&2&1 &0&0&1
\end{array}\right).$$

Then calculate

$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
2&0&0\\
0&2&0\\
0&0&2
\end{array}\right)- \left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1&-1&-1\\
1&-1&0\\
-1&2&1
\end{array}\right)= \left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1&1&1\\
-1&3&0\\
1&-2&1
\end{array}\right).$$

Comment: That's what I got, however I didn't use Gauss method cause it seemed confusing for this problem. I simply got the adjugate.

Comment: The last component is $1$ instead off $-1$.